# How to create a hyperlink to an account by the account text?

Tags: hyperlink

I have Account text (extracted from contact) and want to make a hyperlink to refer to the account.
(I used this code(from Eric Praud) to make a hyperlink from Owner text :

HYPERLINK("/lightning/r/"& OwnerId &"/view", BLANKVALUE( Owner:Queue.QueueName, Owner:User.FirstName &" "& Owner:User.LastName)) )

Comment: In fact, I have a custom object, in which by selecting a Contact, I want the Email and Account are auto-populated(and be clickable). The email is easily there, by putting(Contact__r.Email) in the formula of email field, but I can not use the same for account, and the closest thing is (Contact__r. Account_Name_Text__c) which is just a text and not hyperlink

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this in standard page layout?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Sneh yes, I created a custom object, it has fields : Contact, Account, Email, ... . And I am using all in default page layout

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, Create a new formula field (type Text) or change your existing Account_Name_Text__c field and try this :

```
HYPERLINK("/" & Account__r.Id, Account__r.Name)
```

Enjoy !

Comment: Yes, it works. As I do not have a direct field of accout and it is dependent to contact and I want to extract account from contact, I changed it to : HYPERLINK("/" & Contact__r.AccountId, Contact__r.Account_Name_Text__c)  

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HosseinDehghan Glad to hear, please select my reponse as best answer